# How to check if word exist in a string with php

Tags: php, string, strpos

How can i check if word exist in a string.

I tried strpos but not with good results.

My example
`if(strpos($string, 'As ') !== false)`

And string is :

> "Asthmatic is ruff"

Then it gives me true, as the As is included.

But i need to find word

> "As" or "as"

Example:

> "As i walked" or "If it was as"

Comment: `stripos` should do it.

Comment: That will still match 'Asthmatic'.  He needs the preg_match with word boundaries

Comment: i have word like Astelpaju, and in the beginning there is "As" but i dont want that, i want olny when "As" or "as" is a seperate word

Comment: `'As '` that space in there didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/\b(as)\b/i', $string, $matches)) {
    //$string had the word 'as' in it
}
```

Use preg_match to match regular expressions.
`\b` indicates a word boundary. `i` at the end indicates the match will be case-insensitive

Comment: Add some description and maybe use it in an `if`.

Comment: Works, what does the "/\b" and "\b/i" stands for? not so familiar with regular expressions

Comment: @Gunarves   the `/` characters indicate the start and end of the regular expression pattern and i at the end is a case insensitive modifier.  so `/abc/i` would match abc case insensitive.  the \b means word boundary

Comment: thank you. Can i allso use the same expression for str_replace?

Comment: @Gunarves You can use preg_replace for that http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @Ryan Tuosto how can i make preg_match work with letters like "Ü" "Ö" and "Õ".

Answer (score -1):

Try str**i**pos instead (the case insensitive version of strpos)